# Returning multiple values from a c function using pointers; style of parameter list

Tags: c

What is good programming style for writing C-language functions and function calls to functions which return pointers?

For example, if I have a function `my_function` which return two integers through pointer arguments. How should I call this function, such that it is easy for a person who is not familiar with my code, to see that it returns two values?

And how should I write the function definition?

For example, I could always put the return values last in the parameter list, and
when I call the function, I could add some extra space to separate input arguments from return values.

Also, for the function definition, I could add an empty line with a comment between the input parameters and the return values. For example:

```c
void my_function(
   int a,
   int b,
/* return values */
   int *c,
   int *d)
{
   /* do something */
}

int main()
{
   int a = 1;
   int b = 2;
   int c;
   int d;

   my_function(a,b,   &c, &d);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could note the flow of  information in the function definition:

```
void my_function(
   /*  in */ int  a,
   /*  in */ int  b,
   /* out */ int* c,
   /* out */ int* d)
{
   /* do something */
}
```

This way, it's easy to see what happens. If you export this function, you will also include the comments in the prototype so that everybody could see the direction of information flow.

Furthermore, adhere to one style in your functions. For example, if you write the return values always on the end of the parameter list and someone sees you calling

```
whatever(p1, p2, p3, &p4);
```

one will know that there's a high probability that `p4` is the return value of your function.

Comment: Looks nice yes!.. what about calling the function? Is it ok to leave some space as I suggested in my question?

Comment: @HåkonHægland: see edit: IMHO not needed.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a tool to document the code. E.g. with [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/) you can write:

```
/**
 *  \brief Performs something and stores result in \a c and \a d
 *
 *  \param[in]  a ...
 *  \param[in]  b ...
 *  \param[out] c ...
 *  \param[out] d ...
 *
 *  Detailed description here.
 */
void my_function(int a, int b, int *c, int *d)
{
   /* do something */
}
```

The special comment block has a simple structure (it's a C comment block with some additional markings). So it's easy to read and, at the same time, allows to extract documentation.

Ordering function parameters so that all input-only parameters are before any output parameters is quite common in C but it isn't the only option (e.g. `memcpy`).

Anyway the most important aspect is a uniform code style.

As a general rule I try to avoid OUT parameters **whenever** possible.

Also consider that:

- in the C standard there are precedents for returning structures that contain all the results (the `div` / `ldiv` / C99 `lldiv` functions from `<stdlib.h>`);
- mixing return value and return parameters is usually the least clean option (but having a function that return a status and return data via OUT parameters is sensible in C).

---

Somewhat related:

- [What is best practice on ordering parameters in a function?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101346/what-is-best-practice-on-ordering-parameters-in-a-function)
- [Google C++ Style Guide. Why input-then-output parameter ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934633/google-c-style-guide-why-input-then-output-parameter-ordering)

Comment: ... even better: write annotation comments on your parameters and **generate** the doxygen header from these annotations. This is what I'm doing. With Vim.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on using `doxygen`! I have not used that tool before.. But this inspired me to try it out..